# Android app forced close when Internet is not available

Tags: bug, android-app

I am not sure why issues are being raised again when internet is not available. I have posted some issues regarding internet connectivity and some of them are already marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Step to reproduce the issue:

1. Open any question
2. Make net connection off
3. Now do pull-to-refresh and get forced close :)

P.S. this question is posted by using Stack Exchange Android app :)

Comment: What do you mean by *close*? Do you mean closing an app?

Comment: I guess he means force-close, as in the app crashes.

Comment: 'Force close' is one of the best crash message, you will get it if you are lucky ;)